# How can I sign a message with a Bitcoin private key from terminal

Tags: console, terminal, digital-signature, bitcoin

I'm trying to sign a message with a Bitcoin private key to get a refund from InstaWallet.

Any hints on how to do this from a terminal on OS X?

Comment: You might want to migrate this over to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @stormCloud +1, was just about to suggest that!

Comment: it's a good, general crypto question. although bitcoin is mentioned, i think the answer below might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: To anyone the +1'd this question, please read the text when you hover over the up arrow: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear".  This is off topic for StackOverflow ([bitcoin.se] or maybe [unix.se]), and shows no research effort.

Comment: I've added an edit suggestion in an attempt to address the bitcoin specification in the question text @FakeRainBrigand

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Bitcoin. Probably it should be migrated to bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( page 22, 23 from [An Introduction to Bitcoin, Elliptic Curves and the
Mathematics of ECDSA](https://github.com/bellaj/Blockchain/blob/6bffb47afae6a2a70903a26d215484cf8ff03859/ecdsa_bitcoin.pdf) )

> 4.6 ECDSA
>
> A brief outline of how digital signatures work was given in 2.4.2.
> Bitcoin uses the mathematics of elliptic curves as the underlying
> basis for its digital signature. Recall elliptic curves are defined by
> T = (p, a, b, G, n, h), with Bitcoin using parameters prescribed by
> sep256k1. We also have the private and public key pair (Kpriv, Kpub
> where Kpub = Kpriv × G, as explained in 4.5. If Alice (A) and Bob (B)
> wanted to send a message (or transaction) to each other, this is how
> they would create and verify a digital signature.
>
> 4.6.1 Signature Generation [7]
>
> To sign a message m Alice would do the following.
>
> 1. Select a random integer k, 1 ≤ k ≤ n − 1.
> 2. Compute kG = (x1, y1) and convert x1 to an integer x1.
> 3. Compute r = x1 (mod n). If r = 0 then go to step 1.
> 4. Compute k^−1 (mod n). Where k^−1 is the multiplicative inverse and satisfies k−1

[ ... ]

Either follow the link and continue on, to steps five, six, and seven via page 23; or via a python answer here via Jorky10:
[How to sign and verify signature with ecdsa in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451214/how-to-sign-and-verify-signature-with-ecdsa-in-python)

Comment: might want to convert 'logging.debug' into 'print', for the terminal output

Comment: Does Bitcoin use HMAC digests as signatures?

Comment: @Kebman thanks for the heads up... it doesn't. I've updated the answer for ECDSA.