# How to verify ECC signature from android/java with python

Tags: java, android, python

I write code to sign string android using ECDSA algorithm.
Here is mycode:

```
String origin = txtChuoi.getText().toString();
try {
        byte[] chuoiInput = origin.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithECDSA","SC");
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(chuoiInput);
        signatureBytes = sig.sign();
        txtSign.setText(Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes,Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can verify this sign string in same code app (using Java/Android). Here is my code:

```
String origin = txtChuoi.getText().toString();
try {
      sig = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithECDSA","SC");
      sig.initVerify(publicKey);
      byte[] chuoiInput = origin.getBytes("UTF-8");
      sig.update(chuoiInput);
      txtVerify.setText(sig.verify(signatureBytes)+"");
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

but not I want  to verify it on my ubuntu server.

I have a trouble.
How can I implement verify code using python?
I cant write publickey code to pem file like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEfUnusZsShxFLUuAwwAyFAkGCq3mBy98RXIkTP8YiTO3qmL8w6eMdMadiHfdCG2emktDrUwzNmTr9nMFCFhXdGQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But how about the Signature? And I think (but not sure) it verify on bytes[].

How python do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar question with the answer:
[How to sign and verify signature with ecdsa in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451214/how-to-sign-and-verify-signature-with-ecdsa-in-python)

You'll need to prepare the public key for verification. The PEM file you mentioned has it base64 encoded.